# Redirecting Python Interpreter's IO

Tags: python, linux, stdio, io-redirection

I've written a simple debugger program that can execute a console program and send its output to "out" and "err" files and retrieve its input from an "in" file. Now, I want to extend its functionality to run Python scripts. To do this, I'm thinking I can have the debugger just run the Python interpreter and just interface the Python interpreter with files.

But when I run the Python interpreter in the debugger, I don't see any output like I would with normal programs. The debugger has very detailed error logging and I don't see any errors in the error log file.

I used "ps -A" and it does appear that the debugger has started the Python Interpreter for two reasons: 1) The process ID's are different by one and 2) the debugger exits as soon as I kill -9 the python interpreter ( that tells be that the file descriptors are connected ). Here's the output of ps -All:

```
1 R     0  1565     1 88  80   0 -  1040 -      pts/0    00:01:45 debugger
0 S     0  1566  1565  0  80   0 -  7782 pipe_w pts/0    00:00:00 python.out
```

And the debugger is started like this ( python.out is a copy of the python interpreter ):

```
debugger python.out
```

So I guess my question is, does anyone know why this isn't working? Does the Python interpreter do anything weird to its standard file descriptors?

Edit:

- I also noticed that python.out cannot redirect its IO using python.out > out_file - which may or may not be related to the problem the debugger is having.
- The debugger doesn't use block buffering.
- Here's some io info from /proc/pid/io:

Debugger ( I wrote some data, of length 21, into the "in" file )

```
rchar: 21
wchar: 21
syscr: 300222462
syscw: 1
read_bytes: 0
write_bytes: 0
cancelled_write_bytes: 0
```

Python interpreter

```
rchar: 517268
wchar: 0
syscr: 93
syscw: 0
read_bytes: 0
write_bytes: 0
cancelled_write_bytes: 0
```

Comment: What is a _"a standard .out program"_, and how do you _"redirect its IO to in files"_? Surely the input comes _from_ the `.in` file? Or are you tee-ing the stream, sending it both to the `.in` and the python process?

Comment: a standard .out program, in this case, is a program using the std file descriptors for IO. I'll edit my question to answer your questions more precisely.

Comment: python.out is the python interpreter. I copied it from user/bin to the directory i'm working in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pipe_w` wait state of the Python interpreter is the giveaway: it can't run because it is either trying to read from an empty pipe or write to a full one.

There is block buffering being used either in your code, or the interpreter, or both, and you've not shown us enough to tell which.

**Added in response to comment:**

You think you aren't block buffering, but the stdio library might be doing it without you knowing. Consider the simple:

```
main()
{
    puts("print ('hello, world!')\n");
    sleep(3600);
}
```

When you run this from a terminal, it prints `print ('hello, world!')` on the terminal and then sleeps for an hour, exactly as you'd expect. That's because the stdio library detects that `stdout` is a terminal and does a `write()` of its buffer on every newline. It does this because people like to see the line-buffered output when it is ready. However if you pipe the output of this program into `python`, nothing will show on the terminal for an hour; this is because the the stdio library sees that `stdout` is a pipe and switches to block buffered mode. In block buffered mode, stdio will wait until it has `BUFSIZ` characters to write and on modern machines `BUFSIZ` is 4096 or greater.

When you say "I can confirm that the debugger is reading the input I pass to it", because of this mode switching of stdio, your testing your debugger on the terminal actually tells you nothing about whether the inter-process communication is buffered or not. The output of `ps` suggests that it is buffering. See [setvbuf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setvbuf) for how you might control your buffering.

Or you could have shown your code instead of useless `/proc/n/io`. My `python` reports:

```
rchar: 288789
wchar: 0
syscr: 108
syscw: 0
read_bytes: 0
write_bytes: 0
cancelled_write_bytes: 0
```

but it still hasn't given any output and won't until the hour is up because its `/proc/n/wchan` is

```
pipe_wait
```

as expected.

Comment: my code doesn't use block buffering. I can confirm that the debugger is reading the input I pass to it. is there a way I can confirm that the interpreter is reading that info? Or, is there a way to check if the interpreter uses block buffering?

Comment: @TaylorFlores see added above.

Comment: Okay, I'll have to rewrite some of the debugger since setvbuf only works on FILE structs ( I used integers ). Thanks for your response. Even though I haven't tested it, I'll consider it an answer because you seem to be right anyway.